# How to get value from summary XRLabel

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a XRLabel (xrlabel42) which is a sum summary value in my report and another XRLabel (xrlabel49) - I wish to get the value of the summary xrlabel42 in the before print event to set the text value of xrlabel49

[VB.NET]

```
Private Sub XrLabel42_BeforePrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles XrLabel42.BeforePrint
    XrLabel49.Text = XrLabel42.Text
End Sub
```

I currently get the value 0 not the summary value [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6G8Q.png)

How can I get the summary value from xrlabel42 to xrlabel49.text?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do the following to get the required value from a summary cell:

```
string value = this.xrlabel42.Summary.GetResult().ToString();
```

Also if you are doing this in xrlabel42 BeforePrint the value will be 0 as the report has not yet calculated this summary value - The above code should go into the xrlabel49 BeforePrint.